# Sorting a list by last order date

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am currently trying to take a list of orders on a set of customers and find the last order of each of these customers, check the items on that order and compare it to a list of strings in NHibernate.. However I am completely stumped on how I can take the customers and find their last order date as I am using NHibernate 1.2 (I can't upgrade this.) so I have no access to the LINQ functionality in newer versions.

If anyone could possibly point me in the right direction that would be awesome, so far I have this.

```
IList<Order> people = new List<Order>();
ICriteria criteria = CoreHttpModule.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order));
string[] instrumentList = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" };

public void CleanList()
{
    criteria.CreateAlias("Customer", "customer", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    criteria.CreateAlias("Purchaser", "purchaser", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    criteria.CreateAlias("Agent", "agent", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
}
```

Comment: You could begin by giving us some examples of how the `Order`, `Customer`, `Purchasers`, `Agent` objects are connected. I don't even see the set of `Customer`s you speak about. There is only an `instrumentList`

Comment: Sorry, basically the way this works is that the Order is a complete order information table that has full information regarding it and the other three are connected to it via the customer_id

Comment: Normally you begin by writing the SQL query you want and then you translate it to NHibernate. Criteria query maps nearly 1:1 to SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

First you build the query in SQL:

```
SELECT O.* 
    FROM Orders order1
    INNER JOIN Customers customer1 ON customer1.ID = order1.CustomerId
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Orders order2 
            INNER JOIN Customers customer2 ON customer2.Id = order2.CustomerId
            WHERE customer2.Id = customer1.Id 
            ORDER BY order2.OrderDate DESC
    )
```

Then you try building the same query in NHibernate

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Order), "order2")
    .CreateAlias("Customer", "customer2", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("customer2.ID", "customer1.ID"))
    .AddOrder(NHibernate.Criterion.Order.Desc("order2.OrderDate"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("order2.ID"))
    .SetMaxResults(1);

ICriterion condition = Subqueries.Exists(dc);

ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order), "order1")
    .CreateAlias("Customer", "customer1", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(condition);
```

The only big limit that NHibernate has is that you can't create JOINs on the fly: you can only JOIN on tables (and on fields) JOINed in the mapping file.

Note that this is built with `Order`s first, so `Customer`s without `Order`s won't "appear".

**You'll have to change the field names.**